# Ошибка при перегрузке оператора '<<'

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, операторы

Интерфейс

```
class Money
{
private:
double Summa;
public:
friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& outputStream, const Money& amount);
}
```

Реализация

```
ostream& operator <<(ostream& outputStream, const Money& amount)
{
    outputStream << amount.Summa;
    return outputStream;
}
```

Comment: Приведите минимальный для компиляции пример. кода и сообщение об ошибке

Comment: Вы что-то выдумываете. При таком наборе объявлений такой ошибки быть не может. Вы не указали какой-то принципиальный момент.

Comment: [Так](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Dt2Wv4lrk78qzKpb) все компилируется.

Comment: Выложил [весь код](https://hastebin.com/ewivuvufod.cpp), покажите где я ошибся.

Comment: У меня и полный код [компилируется](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/de2d5f368538469b). Текст ошибки - в студию, дословно.

Comment: Ваш код не будет компилироваться с совсем другой ошибкой: компилятор не знает, что такое `ostream` в файле `Header.h`. Вы же нам рассказываете про какие-то "дружественные функции". В приведенном вами коде не может быть ошибки "дружественная функция не видит закрытые поля". Перестаньте выдумывать сказки и либо приводите реальный код, либо приводите реальные сообщения об ошибках.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Вы фактически дописали `using namespace std;` в заголовочный файл. В авторском коде ничего подобного нет.

Comment: @AnT Да, недоглядел.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не указали пространство имен в заголовочном файле. Это правильно, но компилятор не понимает, что такое `ostream`. Исправьте объявление на

```
    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& outputStream, const Money& amount);
```

Но у вас есть момент хуже - бесконечная рекурсия... Конструктор копирования вызывает оператор присваивания, а тот вызывает конструктор копирования...

Comment: Оператор присваивания действительно творческий... Начинать надо было с Си. Это абстрактное программирование меня достало окончательно...